How do I make a text grow from the center of a button?
I'm trying to create a home page where there are 6 buttons and when a user pass the cursor hover them they shrink and a text expand from the center of each button.
I managed to get this:


body {
  background-color: white;
}

.button-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.image-button img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.image-button:hover img {
  transform: scale(0.6); 
}

.button-container span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 8vh;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
}

.image-button:hover + span {
  font-size: 32vh;
  opacity: 1;
}
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="image-button">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/1442590746571-RPGKIXWGOO671REUNMCB/image-asset.gif" alt="Button Image">
  </button>
  <span>text1</span>
  <button class="image-button">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/1442590746571-RPGKIXWGOO671REUNMCB/image-asset.gif" alt="Button Image">
  </button>
  <span>text2</span>
  <button class="image-button">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/1442590746571-RPGKIXWGOO671REUNMCB/image-asset.gif" alt="Button Image">
  </button>
  <span>text3</span>
</div>



As you can see is not very clean, it glitch a bit, and the text grow from the center of the screen and not from the center of the button.
What should I change?

If you're using a button, presumably you want the text to be clickable, so why not put the text inside the button?

@DBS I tried doing so but the text wasn't going outside of of the button, I want the text to be bigger then the button



body {
  background-color: white;
}

.button-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: 10px;
}

.image-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  background-image: url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/1442590746571-RPGKIXWGOO671REUNMCB/image-asset.gif');
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


.image-button span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease;
}

.image-button:hover {
  transform: scale(0.6);
}

.image-button:hover span {
  font-size: 16vh;
  opacity: 1;
}
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="image-button">
    <!-- <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/1442590746571-RPGKIXWGOO671REUNMCB/image-asset.gif" alt="Button Image"> -->
    <span>text1</span>
  </button>

  <button class="image-button">
    <!-- <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/1442590746571-RPGKIXWGOO671REUNMCB/image-asset.gif" alt="Button Image"> -->
    <span>text2</span>
  </button>

  <button class="image-button">
    <!-- <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/55fc0004e4b069a519961e2d/1442590746571-RPGKIXWGOO671REUNMCB/image-asset.gif" alt="Button Image"> -->
    <span>text3</span>
  </button>
</div>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
